# How to read a COMPRESS()-ed H2 blob column via JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, h2, deflate

I have a file-based H2 database (engine version 1.4.196) with a `mediumblob` column containing data returned by the `COMPRESS()` function:

```
create table foo (compressed_data mediumblob);
...
insert into foo (compressed_data) values (COMPRESS(STRINGTOUTF8('Test'), 'DEFLATE'));
```

(The table is created and filled by flyway.)

I'd like to read this data in a JDBC client without calling `DECOMPRESS()` first. (I want to do the decompression client-side for compatibility with another system). I've tried to read the data via an `InflaterInputStream`, which can uncompress DEFLATE data:

```
try (InputStream dbStream = rs.getBinaryStream("compressed_data");
     InflaterInputStream inflaterStream = new InflaterInputStream(dbStream);
    ) {
        inflaterStream.read();
        ...
```

But this causes an error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    ...
```

Is there any way I can get `InflaterInputStream`-compatible compressed data from a column in H2?

Comment: H2 is open source, and in Java: you could always check what H2 does internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using H2 JDBC to access the database you can simply retrieve the compressed data with `getBytes` and use the `expand` method of `org.h2.tools.CompressTool` to uncompress it:

```java
// .java source file is Cp1252 encoded
String sql = "SELECT COMPRESS(STRINGTOUTF8('fermé'), 'DEFLATE') AS foo";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
rs.next();
byte[] bytesOut = rs.getBytes(1);
byte[] expanded = org.h2.tools.CompressTool.getInstance().expand(bytesOut);
String strOut = new String(expanded, "UTF-8");
```